# On click listener doesn't work

Tags: android

```
public class ChatHeadDrawerService extends Service {

      private WindowManager windowManager;
      private ImageButton chatHead;

      @Override public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // Not used
        return null;
      }

      @Override public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

        chatHead = new ImageButton(this);
        chatHead.setImageResource(R.drawable.x);

       chatHead.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            // Start new list activity
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent mainIntent = new Intent(ChatHeadDrawerService.this,
                        MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(mainIntent);
            }
        });


        final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

        params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
        params.x = 0;
        params.y = 100;

        windowManager.addView(chatHead, params);


        chatHead.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {



              private int initialX;
              private int initialY;
              private float initialTouchX;
              private float initialTouchY;

              @Override public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {


                switch (event.getAction()) {
                  case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    initialX = params.x;
                    initialY = params.y;
                    initialTouchX = event.getRawX();
                    initialTouchY = event.getRawY();
                    return true;
                  case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    return true;
                  case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    params.x = initialX + (int) (event.getRawX() - initialTouchX);
                    params.y = initialY + (int) (event.getRawY() - initialTouchY);
                    windowManager.updateViewLayout(chatHead, params);
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
              }
        });
      }
```

On click listener doesn't work  in chat head but chat head work correctly and move all over the screen i want to open intent when click on the chat head thanks for helping ......................

this the line that doesnt work

```
 chatHead.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            // Start new list activity
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent mainIntent = new Intent(ChatHeadDrawerService.this,
                        MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(mainIntent);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is in OnTouchListener. As soon as it returns true in MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN event, this listener consumes your click event. 
Read a bottom line of this [reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html)

Comment: You can execute your OnClick code under ACTION_UP case. But this way has one problem - onClick = fast ACTION_DOWN + ACTION_UP (in simple words), but if you type your Click code to ACTION_UP it will be executed also in LongClick.

Comment: I want to open intent when i click on chat head what code can i edit or add

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
    if ((Math.abs(initialTouchX - event.getRawX()) < 5) && (Math.abs(initialTouchY - event.getRawY()) < 5)) {
        Log.e(TAG, "It's a click!");
    } else {
        Log.e(TAG, "You moved the head");
    }
    return true;
```